# Remove separator from unused UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` with a custom cell, in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method i'm using the count of the objects in the data source array.

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { 

    return [self.myArray count];
}
```

When i run the app and display the list, everything is perfect except one thing. For example if i have 4 objects in the array the table view displays 4 cells with the right content, but i see the upcoming empty cells, because they have a separator. So i would like to remove every separator that comes after the last row, that shows content. I don't understand why happens this, because i think the cell's count should be equal to the array's count originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set 0 to the size of your footer to clear those "ghost" cells.

```
self.myTable.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well! I'm just wondering that it's a legal way to do it? I mean it doesn't opposite with the human interface guide?

Comment: I succesfully submitted apps that use this and I think most people do it this way when they need it. You could also shorten the UITableView to the size you need but that would look exactly the same unless you have some footer following it closely.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a proper way to do this, but I can think of a workaround that isn't too bad, and definitely doesn't go against any of Apple's restrictions. You can set your tableView's tableFooterView to a solid white (or appropriately styled) view, with the proper height (the screen height - 4 * cellHeight).

Comment: I think it would make things more difficult in my case, because the cells has dynamic heights, custom elements and i'm using a lot of constraints, so i don't wanna make calculations.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```
(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Without  the rest of the code is difficult to answer it. Is the table view delegated to itself?

Answer (score 0):

If your cell is a custom one then add a UIView at the bottom of the content view of the cell with height of 1px and same width as the cell with some color to act like a separator, Then add the code below to avoid the table view cell separator like :

```
 [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use,

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```